# Advanced documentation for Knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Is there any official documentation for advanced techniques in Knockout? I'm referring to functions such as: ko.utils.x, ko.isObservable, etc.

There doesn't seem to be anything relating to these topics on the official www.knockoutjs.com site, unless it's deeply hidden.

Comment: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html and https://github.com/knockout/knockout/tree/master/src

Comment: ko.isObservable is [found here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) for instance, for ko.utils there doesn't seem to be none, but I think you could count [RP's blog](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) as "official" as well

Comment: there is also really good resource on http://www.knockmeout.net